# How to evaluate a string in its template with given values in ruby

Tags: ruby

there is a string like this and it is stored in a file

```
#{date}abcde.doc
```

I want to be able to read this string and replace #{date} with

```
Date.today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Is there any way to parse the template and do the evaluation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, however...

It would be easier if you used hash replacement, like this:

```
s = "%{date}abcde.doc"
s % { date: Time.now.strftime(etc) }
```

Or just use ERb.

As-is you're using string interpolation so it would need to be evaled, I think.